# Implementing CQRS event sourcing in C#

Tags: c#, cqrs, masstransit, event-sourcing

I have a simple business logic, I don't want to use Domain Driven Design (DDD) in my project.
All I want is to implement the following:

- Write on SQL.
- serialize the object as JSON and add it to a queue.
- A worker read the serialized object and insert it to into MongoDB
- the application reads from MongoDB not SQL

I found about CQRS and event sourcing and also about MassTransit, but I'm honestly lost.

I think what I want is simple, but I don't know if I'm going to the right direction, I appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you think that event sourcing and queues are the right tools?

Comment: @jgauffin, I want to write into sql server and read from MongoDB or whatever noSQL DB, because I have a lot of reads.
I reached articles that talks about event sourcing and CQRS, that's why I'm asking, is it the right direction ? because I'm lost.

Comment: A regular RDBMS (with a flat table without relations) and an index will be very fast and you'll have a lot less complexity. It's also a lot cheaper to buy GBs of ram for the DB server than to maintain a complex solution. Would also be interesting to see what you mean with a lot of reads?

Comment: check out github - thats where I learned a lot.  Also books.  I have an example project here: https://github.com/volak/DDD.Enterprise.Example

Comment: @jgauffin, RDBMS might not be useful for me, I might use more than one database servers in the future.
Reading from the database is going to be way more than writing on the database, I'm picked noSQL because of the performance, if I used RDBMS for reads, I will have to do a lot of joins, 5 joins at least, and the performance is important in my case.

Comment: @Charles, thank you for the sample, but I don't want to implement DDD, it was useful though, thank you.

Comment: No, you do not have to do joins in sqlserver. You can store complex objects as JSON in a column if you want object hierarchy. Many RDBMS support clustering. Still. how many writes/reads do you expect per second? How many rows will your table have?

Comment: @jgauffin, RDBMS support clustering, but it might be painful to do that, it's much easier with noSQL.
I currently have more than a million in the database. it's all about retrieving profiles and their info. I don't know how many reads I expect, but in a ratio I guess it's 8:2 read:write or even more.

Comment: 1M rows should not require a cluster. It's not that much data. imho it's dangerous to select components based on assumptions. Picking things that you have never worked with is also dangerous. Event sourcing is not a good fit for reviewing profiles.

Comment: @jgauffin, I appreciate your help.
1M is not much, it's just what I have currently.
I'm just confused, do you recommend to stick with RDBMS at the moment and scale later ? or go to a different approach ?

Comment: @IbraheemAl-Saady I suggest you base your decision on metrics collected through benchmarks using realistic data for your problem area, not on stuff people find cool on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bad idea.. I went down this path and CQRS is harder with CRUD...

Don't worry about all the network event bus stuff ( mass transit ) start with simple CQRS on github ( its event sourced but simple) and evolve from there.  , then write a persistence adapter.  SQL is ok to start but in the long term when you do a bigger app you will look for something else SQL has very poor insert performance especially through EF.

Note Event sourcing is simpler for complex applications with a lot of logic  but it has a base complexity overhead.  A lot of the online examples are for very large and complex apps .